# Why are all images broken on my Github Pages?

Tags: image, github, github-pages, broken-links

I'm a new user of Git/Github and I'm traying to use Gitghub Pages for my project but for some reason the images are all broken. I was looking for solution but I did find no one with same issue :(

**Github Pages:** https://dannotfound.github.io/Alessandra/

**Github Repository:** https://github.com/dannotfound/Alessandra

Someone knows why is it happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages uses [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and [Jekyll will ignore files and directories with underscores](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/55). This allows you to have files and directories within your repository yet are not exposed via the web server. Such as `_config.yml` and `_includes/`.

The fix is to rename `_img` to `img` and change your links.

Comment: Omg it's so simple. I read about Github being case sensitive but none about underscores. very thank you!

Comment: @DanielCarvalhodeOliveira I couldn't find clear documentation about underscores either. I'm surprised it's not in their troubleshooting FAQ.